# Android Room one-to-one relation (getting foreign fields)

Tags: android, android-room, android-database

I want to implement **android ROOM** to my project. 
But I can not solve one-to-one relation between Order(customer_id) and Customer(id).

*Is it possible to fill customer* (@Ignore protected Customer customer) field in OrderDao interface?

I can solve only java codes. Is there any other methods?

```
//    Customer.java 
@Entity (tableName = "t_customer")
public class Customer {
  @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
  @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
  protected String mId;

  @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
  protected String mName;

}

// Order.java
@Entity(tableName = "t_order",
    foreignKeys = {
    @ForeignKey(entity = Customer.class,
        parentColumns = "id",
        childColumns = "customer_id",
        onDelete = SET_NULL) }
public class Order {
  @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
  @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
  protected String mId;

  @ColumnInfo(name = "description")
  protected String mDescription;

  @ColumnInfo(name = "customer_id")
  protected String mCustomerId;

  @Ignore
  **protected Customer customer;**

//....  
}

//OrderDao.java

@Dao
public interface OrderDao {

  @Query("SELECT * from t_order ORDER BY id DESC")
  LiveData<List<Order>> listByIds();

  @Query("SELECT * from t_order WHERE id = :id LIMIT 1")
  LiveData<Order> readById(long id);

//....
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of right now there is no way to fill `Customer` automatically. You'll need to create another POJO named `OrderWithCustomer` and it will **probably** looks as shown below:

```
public class OrderWithCustomer {

    @Embedded
    private Order order;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    private String customerName;
}
```

And in your `DAO`:

```
@Dao
interface OrderDao {

    @Query("SELECT t_order.* name FROM t_order LEFT JOIN t_customer ON t_order.customer_id = t_customer.id")
    public List<OrderWithCustomer> getOrderWithCustomer();

}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. I was expecting 1-1 relation like @ToOne annotation in greendao. I hope google add this annotation.

Comment: I hope the same. Relations in Room are really tricky.

Comment: can you select all columns from both tables (as long as there unique names) using this emthod?

Comment: @TheRealChx101 Yes, you can

Comment: Thanks. I was having difficulties with Room so I just ended up abandoning it in favor of ObjectBox. It's must better than Room in my opinion. It does support Rx and Android's paging library. It's awesome